Filtering Products by multiple (a set of) Many to Many Variations
Can anyone please help me to filter a products table, by a set of Many to Many Variations in SQL Server? Filtering by a single variation is straightforward, but I can't get my head around multiple.
I have setup a SQL fiddle here:
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=489fb6f3-1b8e-4256-88be-11a4c900e900
PRODUCTS



Id
Name




1
Bike 1


2
Bike 2



Variations



Id
Name




1
Style


2
Colour


3
Wheel Size



VariationValues



Id
VariationId
ValueName




1
1
MTB


2
1
Tourer


3
1
Racer


4
2
Red


5
2
Blue


6
2
Black


7
3
26 inch


8
3
29 inch



ProductVariations



Id
ProductId
VariationValueId




1
1 (Bike 1)
1 (Style = MTB)


2
1 (Bike 1)
5 (Colour = Blue)


3
1 (Bike 1)
7 (Wheel Size = 26 inch)


4
2 (Bike 2)
2 (Style= Tourer)


5
2 (Bike 2)
4 (Colour = Red)


6
2 (Bike 2)
7 (Wheel Size = 26 inch)


7
3 (Bike 3)
3 (Style = Racer)


9
3 (Bike 3)
2 (Colour = Black)


10
3 (Bike 3)
8 (Wheel Size = 29 inch)


11
4 (Bike 4)
1 (Style = MTB)


12
4 (Bike 4)
2 (Colour = Black)


13
4 (Bike 4)
7 (Wheel Size = 26 inch)



-- This query gets the bikes that match this style
DECLARE @Style int = 1; -- MTB (should find Bike 1 and Bike 4, which it does)

SELECT p.Name, vv.ValueName --,vv.Id AS ValueId, pv.VariationValueId
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN ProductVariations pv ON pv.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN VariationValues vv ON vv.Id = pv.VariationValueId
WHERE pv.VariationValueId = @Style
ORDER BY p.Name

-- But the problem is, how to select products that match  multiple variations?

 -- This will NOT work
DECLARE @Style int = 1; -- MTB
DECLARE @Colour int = 5; -- BLUE
DECLARE @WheelSize int =7; -- 26 inch

SELECT p.Name, vv.ValueName --,vv.Id AS ValueId, pv.VariationValueId
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN ProductVariations pv ON pv.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN VariationValues vv ON vv.Id = pv.VariationValueId
WHERE pv.VariationValueId = @Style
AND pv.VariationValueId = @Colour
AND pv.VariationValueId = @WheelSize
ORDER BY p.Name

Thanks for any help

This is the big disadvantage that comes with using EVA tables instead of straight-forward column names. You get some flexibility at the cost of more complex queries. And you allow a bike to have no style but three wheel sizes for instance. (And if you add very different products, say shirts, they can get a wheel size, too.) Sometimes we cannot avoid EVA tables, but if we can, we should.

I completely agree - it's not how I would normally approach variations at all, but I've always wanted to try the flexibility of doing it this way. It's been problematic from the get-go, but that could just be me struggling to wrestle with the excessive joins (IMHO)

Aggregation is one canonical way to approach this.  Assuming you just want matching product names alone, you may use:
SELECT p.Name
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN ProductVariations pv
    ON pv.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN VariationValues vv
    ON vv.Id = pv.VariationValueId
WHERE pv.VariationValueId IN (@Style, @Colour, @WheelSize)
GROUP BY p.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pv.VariationValueId) = 3
ORDER BY p.Name;

The idea here is to aggregate by product name, restricting to only records having the three variation values you want, then assert that all 3 variations are present for each matching product.
If you want to also select other columns, then place the above into a CTE, and filter based on matching products only:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.Name
    FROM Products p
    INNER JOIN ProductVariations pv ON pv.ProductId = p.Id
    INNER JOIN VariationValues vv ON vv.Id = pv.VariationValueId
    WHERE pv.VariationValueId IN (@Style, @Colour, @WheelSize)
    GROUP BY p.Name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pv.VariationValueId) = 3
)

SELECT p.Name, vv.ValueName, vv.Id AS ValueId, pv.VariationValueId
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN ProductVariations pv
    ON pv.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN VariationValues vv
    ON vv.Id = pv.VariationValueId
WHERE p.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM cte);


That's fantastic, thank you so much for your time.
